# ERROR C2144 for a global variable in Visual C++ 2017

Tags: c++17

I encountered  an error code C2144 while building this code for testing purpose.

[image: Error Code:C2144]

I am actually building a native  C++  dll application for getting the battery information:
Here is the code for BatteryInfromation.cpp File:

```
  // BATTERY INFORMATION.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StatusCodes.h"

SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS SYS;
STATUS battery_info_init(void )
{
    if ( GetSystemPowerStatus( &SYS ) )
        return SUCCESS;

    return FALIURE;


}
STATUS ChargingState( )
{
    if ( battery_info_init( ) )
    {
        switch ( SYS.ACLineStatus )
        {
        case 1:
            return ONCHARGING; break;
        case 0:
            return ONBATTERY; break;
        case 128:
            return NOBATTERY; break;
        case 255:
            return UNKNOWNSTATUS; break;
        default:
            return FALIURE; break;
        }
    }
    else
        return FALIURE;

}
```

Here is my code for macro definition:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
/* Status Code: Contains the Status Codes returned by the BATTERYINFORMATION.cpp*/


typedef unsigned char  STATUS
# define ONBATTERY       0x64 
# define ONCHARGING      0x65
# define HIGHBATTERY     0x66
# define LOWBATTERY      0x67
# define CRITICALBATTERY 0x68
# define NOBATTERY       0x80
# define UNKNOWNSTATUS   0xFF
# define SUCCESS         0x01
# define FALIURE         0x00
# define MEDIUMBATTERY   0x69
```

Here is the Code for the unit test File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "E:\UNIVERSAL ARDUINO CONTROLLER\CODE\SYSTEM PROFILE\BATTERY INFORMATION\BATTERY INFORMATION\StatusCodes.h"
#include "E:\UNIVERSAL ARDUINO CONTROLLER\CODE\SYSTEM PROFILE\BATTERY INFORMATION\BATTERY INFORMATION\BATTERY INFORMATION.cpp"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Battery_Information_Functions_Test
{       
    TEST_CLASS(BatteryInformationTests)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD( Battery_Information_Initialization )
        {

            Assert::AreEqual<int>( ChargingState() , SUCCESS , L"GetSystemPowerStatus() failed to initialize " );
        }
        TEST_METHOD(ChargingState_in_AC)
        {

            Assert::AreEqual<int>( ChargingState( ) , ONCHARGING , L"Function not returning ONCHARGING STATE " );
        }
        TEST_METHOD( ChargingState_in_DC )
        {

            Assert::AreEqual<int>( ChargingState() ,(int) ONBATTERY , L"Function not returning ONBATTERY STATE" );


        }
        TEST_METHOD( ChargingState_in_UnknownStatus )
        {
            if(ChargingState() != ONBATTERY && ChargingState() != ONCHARGING )
            Assert::Fail( L"Function not able to get the information associated with charging" );

        }
    };
}
```

This is a small part of what i have started writing. If anyone could help me it would be of great help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From reading the error, you are missing a ";" in the "StatusCodes.h" file.

Comment: I noticed that sir but why does it point to the main file and not status codes.h file

Comment: I got it sir.  Thank you very much

Comment: Think of the #include as inserting the text right there in the file.  The compiler does not know that there is a missing ; in "line 10" (the H file) until it reaches "line 11" (the variable declaration). "Preceding" = before.

Comment: yes sit i understood that. Thanks very much for the help